# Cross product in $\mathbb R^n$ (from Spivak's book)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, differential-geometry, manifolds

Spivak defines **cross product** in this way:

> $\quad$ We conclude this section with a construction which we will restrict to $\mathbf{R}^n$. If $v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1}\in\mathbf{R}^n$ and $\varphi$ is defined by $$\varphi(w)=\det\pmatrix{v_1 \\ \vdots \\ v_{n-1} \\ w},$$ then $\varphi\in\Lambda^1(\mathbf{R}^n)$; therefore there is a unique $z\in\mathbf{R}^n$ such that $$\langle w,z\rangle=\varphi(w)=\det\pmatrix{v_1 \\ \vdots \\ v_{n-1} \\ w}$$ This $z$ is denoted $v_1\times\cdots\times v_{n-1}$ and called the **cross product** of $v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1}$.

Why such a $z$ exists and why is it unique? When solving problems involving this notion, how do I find this $z$ explicitly (if it's possible)?

Also, what's the meaning of this cross product? Many sources say that the usual cross product in $\mathbb R^3$ can't be generalized to higher dimensions.

Comment: Cross product in $\Bbb R^3$ cannot be generalised to higher dimensions if you restrict your attention to binary products. In higher dimensions, those cross products are not binary products, but instead takes $n-1$ many vectors as input.

Comment: I image that earlier in the book there is a theorem that says that if $\varphi \in \Lambda^1(\mathbf R^n)$ then there exists a unique $z \in \mathbf R^n$ such that $\varphi(w) = \langle w, z \rangle$.

Comment: @TrevorGunn I would also think so, but I couldn't find it (or couldn't recognize it if it's stated in a different form).

Comment: You might be interested in [Hodge stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator).

Answer (score 3):

Just for kicks, here's a  proof of the Riesz representation theorem that Ivo talks about in the (much easier) finite dimension case.

Suppose $V$ is a real, finite dimensional inner product space.  Let $f:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a linear functional.  We claim that there is a unique $z\in V$ for which $f(w) = \langle w,z\rangle$ for all $w\in V$.

First, if $f$ is identically $0$, then $z=0$ works, and only $z=0$ works because $0 =f(z) = \langle z,z\rangle = |z|^2$.  Thus, we may assume that $f$ is not identically $0$.  Let $v\in V$ with $f(v) \neq 0$.

Linearity implies that $f$ is surjective.  In more detail, if $r\in \mathbb{R}$ is any real number, then $f\left(\frac{r}{f(v)} v\right) = \frac{r}{f(v)} f(v) = r$.

By the rank-nullity theorem (which uses finite dimensionality of $V$), it follows that $\ker f\subseteq V$ is a codimension $1$ subspace.  Then $(\ker f)^\bot$ is $1$-dimensional.  Choose a non-zero $y\in (\ker f)^\bot$.  Note that $\langle y,v\rangle \neq 0$, for if it is $0$, then $v\in ((\ker f)^\bot)^\bot = \ker f$, contradicting the fact that $f(v) \neq 0$.

Finally, set $z = \frac{f(v)}{\langle y,v\rangle} y$.  I claim that this $z$ works.

For any $w\in V$, we break it up into $w_1 + \lambda v$ where $w_1\in \ker f$.

Then $f(w) = f(\lambda v) = \lambda f(v)$.  On the other hand, $$\langle w,z\rangle = \langle w_1 + \lambda v, z\rangle = \lambda \left\langle v,  \frac{f(v)}{\langle v,w\rangle}y\right\rangle = \lambda f(v).$$  So they match.

What about uniqueness?  If $z_1$ and $z_2$ both work, then for any $w\in V$, we have $\langle w,z_1\rangle = f(w) = \langle w,z_2\rangle$ which implies that $\langle w, z_1 - z_2\rangle = 0$ for all $w\in V$.  Choosing $w= z_1 - z_2$, we see that $|z_1 - z_2|^2 = 0$, which means $z_1 = z_2$.

Answer (score 2):

It exists because the inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is non-degenerate and we apply the [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem) (whose proof in the finite dimensional case is easy) for the linear functional $\varphi\colon \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ given by $$\varphi(w) = \det(v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1},w).$$The Riesz vector $z$ satisfies $\langle w,z\rangle =\varphi(w)$ for all $w \in \Bbb R^n$, and is then denoted by $v_1\times\cdots\times v_{n-1}$. If you write $$v_1\times\cdots \times v_{n-1} = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle e_i,z\rangle e_i$$by orthonormal expansion and compute $\langle e_i, z\rangle = \det(v_1,\cdots,v_{n-1},e_i)$ using Laplace expansion, you'll get a formal expression for $v_1\times\cdots \times v_{n-1}$ with a determinant just like the $3$-dimensional case. For example, in $\Bbb R^4$ we have $$e_1\times e_2 \times e_3 = \begin{vmatrix} e_1 & e_2 & e_3 & e_4 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{vmatrix} = e_4,$$and so on.

Answer (score -1):

For $n=3$, Spivak's definition is basically the way that 3Blue1Brown describes a cross product in https://youtu.be/BaM7OCEm3G0, and I like it a lot more than the usual parallelogram-and-right-hand-rule approach.

As for generalizing, there is no way to combine **two** vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ into a new vector that behaves the way $\times$ does in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but this linear functional approach is a perfectly good way to combine $n-1$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in a way that behaves just like $\times$ does in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: When you provide an answer to a question on MSE, you should strive to make your answer as self-contained as possible.  In your first paragraph, it is nearly impossible to know what you are talking about, because you haven't summarized the video to which you have linked.  Regarding your second paragraph, I don't see what you mean by a linear functional approach which combines $n-1$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Can you please expand on that idea?

Comment: I didn't know about the MSE convention. Still, the first paragraph is referring to the original question. I'm not trying to talk about anything new, I'm just giving a source that, in my opinion, has a better explanation of the same concept. I call this concept the "linear functional approach" in the second paragraph.