# Problem about cross product from Spivak

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, differential-geometry, cross-product

Below is a problem from Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds:

1. If $v\in \mathbf R^2$, what is $v\times$?
2. If $v_1\dots,v_{n-1}\in \mathbf R^n$ are linearly independent, show that $[v_1,\dots,v_{n-1},v_1\times\dots\times v_{n-1}]$ is the usual orientation of $\mathbf R^n$.

See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2718158/cross-product-in-mathbb-rn-from-spivaks-book/) for Spivak's definition of cross product.

For 1, I don't even understand what this question asks.

For 2, I think this amounts to showing that the matrix whose columns are $v_1,\dots,v_{n-1},v_1\times\dots\times v_{n-1}$ has positive determinant. But I don't know how to proceed using Spivak's confusing definition.

Comment: For $1.$ it looks like the question is to describe the map $w\mapsto v\times w$.

Comment: In $\Bbb R^2$, you can only take the cross product of a vector with nothing (right? in general, you take the cross-product of $n-1$ vectors in $\Bbb R^n$) and then $\langle w,v\times\rangle = \det(v,w)$. So what does this make the *vector* "$v\times$" geometrically?

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks! If $v=(a,b)$, then $v\times = (-b,a)$. So looks like $v\times$ is the vector $v$ rotated by $\pi/2$ in the clockwise direction.

Comment: You mean counterclockwise, I think :)

Comment: For 2, I think if we transpose the matrix I mentioned, the determinant will not change, and it will follow from the definition that this determinant is equal to the dot product of $v_1\times\dots\times v_{n-1}$ with itself, which is nonnegative. But to conclude that it's positive, we need to know that the cross product is nonzero. Why is that so? (It must follow from linear independence, but how?)

Comment: Take a nonzero vector orthogonal to all of $v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Hmm... For now I can't see why this implies that the cross product is nonzero.

Comment: Think geometrically of determinant as giving you signed volume of a parallelepiped. If $w$ is orthogonal to the span of $v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}$, then in particular, $v_1,\dots,v_{n-1},w$ are linearly independent and that volume is nonzero.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry, I still don't see why this shows that $v_1\times \dots \times v_{n-1} \ne 0$, even though now everything you said is clear.

Comment: Because its dot product with my $w$ is equal to the determinant of $v_1,\dots,v_{n-1},w$, which we've established is nonzero.

Comment: What is $<,>$ in $<w,z>  = \varphi(w) ?$

Comment: Inner/dot product, @Sou. You should use $\langle,\rangle$ instead of $<,>$. :P

Comment: Thanks @TedShifrin. If $z = v_1 \times \cdots \times v_{n-1}$, just note that $\langle z,z \rangle = \varphi(z) = \det (v_1,\dots,v_{n-1},z) > 0 $

Comment: No, @Sou, you're missing his point. How do you know that if $v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}$ are linearly independent, then $z=v_1\times\dots\times v_{n-1}$ is nonzero?

Comment: @TedShifrin By computing $\langle e_i,z \rangle = \det (v_1,\dots,v_{n-1},e_i)$ for every $i$ ?

Comment: Well, @Sou, or see my suggestion a dozen or so comments up ... At any rate, he saw how to do what you wrote but got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Prof @Ted suggestion is correct. To show that the vector $z:= v_1\times\cdots\times v_{n-1} \neq 0$, do the following. Since $v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}$ is linearly independent, there exists a nonzero vector $v_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$ orthogonal to $v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}$. So $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $z = \sum_{i=1}^n z^i v_i$ is nonzero iff we can show that at least one of the components is nonzero. By definition of $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, that is $\varphi(w) = \langle w,z \rangle = \det (v_1,\dots,v_{n-1},w)$, we have
$$
\det (v_1,\dots,v_n) = \langle v_n ,z \rangle = \langle v_n,z^iv_i \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} z^i \langle v_n,v_i \rangle + z^n \langle v_n,v_n \rangle = 0 + z^n |v_n|^2.
$$ 
Since $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are linearly independent ($\det (v_1,\dots,v_n) \neq 0$)  and $v_n \neq 0$, then $z^n \neq 0$.